# Why twidge app is giving me E: Unable to locate package twidge when trying to do apt-get on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: twitter, terminal, installation

Im trying to install Twidge, twidge  is  a client for microblogging sites such as Twitter http://twitter.com/> and
       Identica http://identi.ca/> (identi.ca).  Microblogging sites let you post short one-
       paragraph  updates,  follow the updates that your friends post, and interact with everyone
       in the site in a conversation style.

Or even an official page for install by terminal,

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/02/twidge-twitter-client-for-linux.html

I tryed to find a solution bu different ways but non of the work so im here. Even appear an official page on Ubunntu site
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/twidge.1.html

Im trying to install this under Ubuntu 18.04 and i've already modified source.list doing

sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

Which is recommended by the official page before mentioned for the new Ubuntu versions. But still getting unable to get the package

## sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

## sudo apt-get update

## sudo apt-get install -y twidge

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package twidge

Comment: What is your programming-related question?

Answer (score 0):

And i recive this question when doing a serch

## sudo apt-cache search twidge

libqt5widgets5 - Qt 5 widgets module
libkf5plotting-dev - development files for kplotting
libkf5plotting5 - KPlotting provides classes to do plotting.
libkf5textwidgets-data - Advanced text editing widgets.
libkf5textwidgets-dev - development files for ktextwidgets
libkf5textwidgets5 - Advanced text editing widgets.
libotbqtwidget-6.4-1 - ORFEO Toolbox library - OTBQtWidget
python-pyqt5 - Python 2 bindings for Qt5
python-qtpy - abtraction layer for PySide/PyQt4/PyQt5 (Python 2)
python3-pyqt5 - Python 3 bindings for Qt5
python3-qtpy - abtraction layer for PySide/PyQt4/PyQt5 (Python 3)
tklib - standard Tk Library